# Prevent ArgumentError when using RSpec Doubles

Tags: ruby, rspec, error-handling, exception, mocking

I am currently trying to raise an error with the following code:

```
class NasaController
  attr_reader :plateau, :current_rover

  def initialize(plateau:)
    @plateau = plateau
    @current_rover = []
  end

  def link_to_rover(robotic_rover)
    raise ArgumentError, "#{robotic_rover.class}" unless robotic_rover.is_a? RoboticRover
    @current_rover = robotic_rover
  end
end
```

and it works! Great! But........

My tests are:

```
describe NasaController do
  subject(:controller) { described_class.new(plateau: plateau) }

  let(:robotic_rover) do
    double(:robotic_rover, #some_methods...)
  end

  let(:plateau) { double(:plateau, rover_landed: landed_rover) }

  describe 'interacting with a rover' do
    context 'when a RoboticRover is used' do
      before { controller.link_to_rover(robotic_rover) }

      it 'can create a link' do
        expect(controller.current_rover).to eq robotic_rover
      end

    context 'when something other than a RoboticRover is used' do
      it 'raises an error at #link_to_rover' do
        expect { controller.link_to_rover(plateau) }.to raise_error 'Error!'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which leads to my second test passing because `controller.link_to_rover(plateau)` does not link a RoboticRover.

But, my first fails because `controller.link_to_rover(robotic_rover)` is also not a RoboticRover, it is a double of a RoboticRover. Does anyone have any guidance on getting around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow `robotic_rover` to receive `is_a?`, with an argument of `RoboticRover`, and have it return true. Try adding the following to the failing test:

```
allow(robotic_rover).to receive(:is_a?).with(RoboticRover).and_return(true)
```

or add to the double:

```
let(:robotic_rover) do
    double(:robotic_rover, is_a?: RoboticRover
end
```

See [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs) for more information.